# How to re-use models and controllers across rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

We are coming up with a new `twitter bootstrap` theme for new functionality within our application.
Our existing functionality will use the existing theme with `models/controllers`.

But I would like to re-use the existing `models/controllers` and use the new twitter bootstrap theme for the new functionality.

How do I go about addressing this and maintain the code bases (the old app will be on host:port1 and new app will be on host:port2)

**Edit :**

My old rails application under `public/javascripts public/stylesheets`. 
Some of the views are under `app/views/foos/`
Some of the views are under `app/views/bars/`

I would the new views under `app/views/cars/`
How should I reference my new index files to point to the new `theme/css` under `app/assets`

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between css manifest files. So for new theme it could be like

```
new_theme.css
 /*
 *= bootstrap_alternative_theme
   ... 
 */

old_theme.css
 /*
 *= bootstrap_original_theme
   ... 
 */
```

And layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if request.port == port1 %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "old_theme" %>
<% else %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag  "new_theme" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to benchwarmer answer, you might have the html and also the javascript modified so you can **define a new layout** and toggle between old and new layout as per your needs.

But for compiling those assets, assuming your assets are not named application.css or application.js, add a line in your application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(new.css new.js)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I tried with your suggestion but there is no effect, am unable to get new layout, it still holds the existing theme !

Comment: @diya, which version of rails your are using, is it < 3.1?